# How to do a WHERE...IN... clause in LinqToSql?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, where-clause

How can I select multiple elements using a WHERE...IN... type of clause as in

```
select * from orders where orderid in (1, 4, 5)
```

in LinqToSql? I'd prefer not to have a lambda expression since they scare me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

LINQ has "Contains" which is like "IN" but expressed the other way round - an element isn't "in" a set, a set "contains" an element.

```
int[] validIds = { 1, 4, 5 };
var query = from order in db.Orders
            where validIds.Contains(order.Id)
            select order
```

This is more simply expressed (IMO) with a lambda though:

```
int[] validIds = { 1, 4, 5 };
var query = db.Orders.Where(order => validIds.Contains(order.Id));
```

I realise lambdas are "new" and therefore scary to some extent, but it's really well worth grabbing hold of them with both hands. They're lovely.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arry = new int[] {1,4,5};

var q = from r in orders
        where Array.IndexOf(array, orderid) != -1
        select r;
```

or

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>(new int[] {1,4,5});
var q = from r in orders
        where lst.Contains(orderid);
        select r;
```

Comment: uh, I guess I still have a problem here: I get an exception when trying to run with a foreach over the resultset. unfortunately I do only have a german exception text for it, but it says something like that the expression "Int32 IndexOf[Int32](Int32[], Int32)" can't be recognized.

Comment: LINQ to SQL doesn't know about IndexOf, but does know about Contains.