# SQL "WHERE IN" query conversion to LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, where-clause

I'm trying to find a way to convert this very complex SQL Query into LINQ and I can't seem to tackle all the embedded "WHERE IN" clauses.  Would someone be so kind as to lend me a helping hand?

Here is the SQL code (don't worry about the stored procedure, it's a count of a row total)

```
SELECT      
    (SELECT pac.Name FROM Account pac WHERE pac.AccountID = AC.ParentAccountID) AS ParentAccountName,
    ac.Name, dv.DeviceID, dv.Manufacturer, dv.Model, dv.SerialNr, dv.PrinterIPAddress,
    (SELECT TOP 1 au.AuditDate FROM PrinterAudit pa WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN Audit au ON au.AuditID = pa.AuditID 
        WHERE pa.DeviceID=dv.DeviceID 
        ORDER BY AuditDate DESC) AS AuditDate,
    dbo.Get_TotalPageCountByDeviceId( DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()), GETDATE(), dv.DeviceID ) as TotalUsageLast3Months
FROM  Account ac WITH (NOLOCK)
          INNER JOIN Device dv ON ac.AccountID = dv.AccountID
WHERE dv.AccountID IN
          ( SELECT au.AccountID FROM Audit au WHERE au.AuditDate >= DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()) )
          AND (dv.Manufacturer + dv.Model) IN 
                (SELECT (dv2.Manufacturer + dv2.Model) 
                FROM Device dv2 
                WHERE dv2.AccountID = dv.AccountID 
                AND dv2.Manufacturer = dv.Manufacturer 
                AND dv2.Model = dv.Model 
                AND (dv2.ERPEquipID IS NOT NULL OR dv2.ERPData IS NOT NULL ) )
                AND dv.ERPEquipID IS NULL AND dv.ERPData IS NULL
                AND dv.DeviceID IN 
                (SELECT pa.DeviceID 
                FROM PrinterAudit pa WITH (NOLOCK) 
                INNER JOIN Audit au ON au.AuditID = pa.AuditID 
                WHERE au.AuditDate >= DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()))
ORDER BY ParentAccountName, ac.Name
```

Final Result:

```
var result =
    (from dv in Device
    where Audit.Any(au => au.AuditDate >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)
        && au.AccountID == dv.AccountID) 
    where Device.Any(dv2 => dv2.AccountID == dv.AccountID
        && dv2.Manufacturer == dv.Manufacturer
        && dv2.Model == dv.Model
        && (dv2.ERPEquipID != null || dv2.ERPData != null)
        && dv.ERPEquipID == null 
        && dv.ERPData == null
        && PrinterAudit.Any(pa => pa.Audit.AuditDate >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3) && pa.DeviceID == dv.DeviceID))
    orderby dv.Account.ParentAccountID, dv.Account.Name
    select new
    {
        ParentAccountName = Account.Where(pac => pac.AccountID == dv.Account.ParentAccountID).Select(pac => pac.Name),
        Name = dv.Account.Name,
        DeviceID = dv.DeviceID,
        Manufacturer = dv.Manufacturer,
        Model = dv.Model,
        SerialNumber = dv.SerialNr,
        PrinterIPAddress = dv.PrinterIPAddress,
        AuditDate = (from pa in PrinterAudit where pa.DeviceID == dv.DeviceID orderby pa.Audit.AuditDate descending select pa.Audit.AuditDate).Take(1),
        TotalUsageLast3Months = (from p in PrinterAudit
                            where p.DeviceID == dv.DeviceID
                            group p by p.DeviceID into total
                            select new
                            {
                                Total = Get_TotalPageCountByDeviceId(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3), DateTime.Now, dv.DeviceID)
                            })

    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a WHERE...IN... clause in LinqToSql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317606/how-to-do-a-where-in-clause-in-linqtosql)

Comment: the issue with the examples, and I've been trying to sort this out for about a month, is that they all have only one WHERE IN clause.  I have 3 nested.  That's where most of the confusion comes.

Comment: I gave the initial reply the answer as it headed me down the right direction and my result set is now sufficiently correct.  thank you for the rapid and accurate reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You convert the SQL `IN` statement to linq with either [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341422.aspx) or [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534338.aspx)

**Contains**

```
from dv in db.Device
where
  (from au in db.Audit
  where au.AuditDate >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)
  select au.AccountID).Contains(dv.AccountID)
```

**Any**

```
from dv in db.Device
where 
   db.Audit.Any(au => au.AuditDate >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3) && 
                au.AccountID == dv.AccountID)
```

Comment: This was covered in Meta-Me Blog, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/03/25/tip-8-how-to-write-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities/